# Symfony2 Form Type as a service with dynamic parameter

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm really interested to know if there is a way to call a service with a dynamic parameter (a string for example)?

Actually I need this for a form type (define as a service), which makes it a little more complex.

The form type :

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $em;
    private $parameter;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, $parameter)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->parameter = $parameter;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The service config

```
my.form_type:
    class: My\Form\Type\Class
    arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: form_name }
```

Then when I need to use it in another form type:

```
class SecondFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('custom', 'my.form_type');
        ;
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to set the "parameters" attribute in the first form type class.
If I was in a controller, I would be able to create some getter/setter methods but here I'm stuck in the form type.

I actually don't instantiate the form type myself, because I also need to inject it the entity manager, that's why I defined it as a service.

Comment: Where do you instantiate the form?

Comment: Which one ? The custom form is instantiated in another form type (embedded forms), by calling the service ID my.form_type. The other one is instantiated in a controller, the normal way. I could send my parameter from that controller, but that means I need to repeat that for every controller/form type that include my custom form type.

Comment: Yes, it would. AFAIK there is no such thing as a dynamic parameter. The only thing you could do is to create a setter in the form type and call the setter from the controller. However, that kinda defeats the purpose of defining your form as a service. I think in this case you'd be best of passing the entity manager and parameter to the forms constructor manually

Comment: To be more specific, the custom form type is supposed to deal with tags stuff (with data transformer, ...), and i wanted to specify a 'context' for tags with a simple string. This tag form type was supposed to be use in several entities form. Another way to do it is to create multiple service declaration for each 'context'. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In that case, multiple service definitions would be a good solution indeed.